# How to dump more than <body> on chrome / chromium headless?

Tags: dom, chromium, google-chrome-headless

Chrome's documentation states:

> The --dump-dom flag prints document.body.innerHTML to stdout:

As per the title, how can more of the DOM object (ideally all) be dumped with Chromium headless? I can manually save the entire DOM via the developer tools, but I want a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 2019-04-23 Google was very active on headless front and many updates happened**

The answer below is valid for the v62 current version is v73 and it's updating all the time.
https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule

I highly recommend checking puppeteer for any future development with headless chrome. It is maintained by Google and it installs required Chrome version together with [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) so you just use puppeteer API by the docs and not worry about Chrome versions and setting up the connection between headless Chrome and dev tools API which allows doing 99% of the magic.

- Repo: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer
- Docs: https://pptr.dev/

---

**Update 2017-10-29 Chrome has already --dump-html flag which returns full HTML, not only body.**

v62 does have it, it is already on stable channel.

Issue which fixed this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752747

Current chrome status (version per channel) https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule

Leaving old answer for legacy

> You can do it with google chrome remote interface. I have tried it and
>   wasted couple hours trying to launch chrome and get full html,
>   including title and it is just not ready yet, i would say.
>
> It works sometimes but i've tried to run it in production environment
>   and got errors time to time. All kind of random errors like
>   `connection reset` and `no chrome found to kill`. Those errors rised
>   up sometimes and it's hard to debug.
>
> I personally use `--dump-dom` to get html when i need body and when i
>   need title i just use `curl` for now. Of course chrome can give you
>   title from SPA applications, which can not be done with only curl if
>   title is set from JS. Will switch to google chrome after having stable
>   solution.
>
> Would love to have `--dump-html` flag on chrome and just get all html.
>   If Google's engineer is reading this, please add such flag to chrome.
>
> **I've created issue on Chrome issue tracker, please click favorite "star" to get noticed by google developers:**
>
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752747
>
> Here is a long list of all kind of flags for chrome, not sure if it's
>   full and all flags:
>   https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ nothing
>   to dump title tag.
>
> This code is from Google's blog post, you can try your luck with this:
>
> ```
> const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
>
> ...
>
> (async function() {
>
> const chrome = await launchChrome();
> const protocol = await CDP({port: chrome.port});
>
> // Extract the DevTools protocol domains we need and enable them.
> // See API docs: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/
> const {Page, Runtime} = protocol;
> await Promise.all([Page.enable(), Runtime.enable()]);
>
> Page.navigate({url: 'https://www.chromestatus.com/'});
>
> // Wait for window.onload before doing stuff.
> Page.loadEventFired(async () => {
>   const js = "document.querySelector('title').textContent";
>   // Evaluate the JS expression in the page.
>   const result = await Runtime.evaluate({expression: js});
>
>   console.log('Title of page: ' + result.result.value);
>
>   protocol.close();
>   chrome.kill(); // Kill Chrome.
> });
>
> })();
> ```
>
> Source:
>   https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Comment: Is this still working? Trying various pages, including this SO one, neither --dump-html nor --dump-dom do anything, nothing in stdout. Tried chromium v67  and google chrome v73 without any luck ...
--print-to-pdf works on the same pages.

Comment: It is valid for v62 current version is v73 Google is actively updated headless related stuff during all these versions.  https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule I highly recommend checking puppeteer for any future development with headless chrome. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `--headless` to get stdout.

```
chromium --incognito \
         --proxy-auto-detect \
         --temp-profile \ 
         --headless \
         --dump-dom https://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html
```

Pipe it all in  `| html2text` to recompile html into text.