# How do I get the html of a page from headless chrome after it has rendered?

Tags: google-chrome, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

For single page web applications is there any way to use headless chrome to pipe the html content back to another program? I just want to use v8 to render the page and get the content back. So many sites aren't scrapable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851729/how-to-dump-more-than-body-on-chrome-chromium-headless

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dump more than <body> on chrome / chromium headless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851729/how-to-dump-more-than-body-on-chrome-chromium-headless)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72312070/485063