# How to get dom with headless-chromium-php

Tags: php, google-chrome-headless

I'm using headless-chromium-php, but `getHtml` function seems to get the **html source code**.
https://github.com/chrome-php/chrome#get-the-page-html

Instead, I want to get the **DOM** displayed in the chrome browser.
so, How can i do it
I want to get the html source after browser rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you surmise, you need to wait for the page to finish loading, including any javascript rendering; have a look at the example earlier on in that documentation
https://github.com/chrome-php/chrome#evaluate-script-on-the-page to get the inner html.